# Discordjs constant spamming and mistakes

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want the bot to show a warning to the commander when commanded on a channel without an NSFW channel.

I prepared some codes but warning text is always spammed on chat and I also get a warning when I use other commands.

Codes:

```
  if (message.channel.nsfw === false) {
    return message.reply("Wrong place, mate!");
  }
}

} else {

//my codes
```

Comment: Do you have any syntax errors?

Comment: I have checked many times. I do not think so.

Answer (score 0):

Should it be

```
 if (message.channel == nsfw) {
    return message.reply("Wrong place, mate!");

  }
}

} else {

//my codes
```

You might also want to add a `message.delete()`

Comment: Thank you for your interest, but I came across the same warning when using other commands.

Comment: wait it should be `message.channel == nsfw`

Answer (score 0):

Should be

> if (message.channel.type == "nsfw") {
> return message.reply("Wrong place, mate!");

}
}

} else {

//my codes

Discord.JS v12 ^^